# Installation hangs

Tags: boot, system-installation

Installation hangs at "Select Language"

Hardware Intel NUC NUC5CPYH MEMORY 8 GB, Storage 500 GB SSD
keyboard and mouse USB wireless
boot/install from USB drive.

version 15.10

Any one have a thought why it's hanging here and a work around?

Thanks

Comment: Check your spellings [Install]

Comment: Are the batteries of the keyboard o.k.?

Answer (score 0):

The typical reason it will hang is due to a faulty iso issue.

When you download the ISO and put it onto a medium,: Perform a checksum on it to verify that this was done properly:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM